# Good examples of consistent/admissible heuristics in non-graphical domains?

Tags: reference-request, search-algorithms

I'm preparing lectures for intro to AI, and would like to give non-boring examples of heuristic functions.

Does anyone know examples of non-trivial consistent/admissible heuristics in non-geographic domains? Ones that appear in recent research papers are preferable.

Many thanks!

Comment: Warnsdorff algorithm for computing a path on a $n \times n$ chessboard : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnightGraph.html. Not recent at all (beginning of 19th century) !

Comment: This is excellent, thanks @JeanMarieBecker